# Subtract one week from current week of the year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am trying to get one week earlier then current week of the year but my sql query is returning  null. here is my query

```
select date_sub(yearweek('2014-01-01'),INTERVAL 1 week)
```

what is wrong with this query

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get `YEARWEEK` of week prior to date, you can do this:
Note: `YEARWEEK` results in 6-digit number, first 4 digits are week year, trailing 2 digits are week number.

```
SELECT YEARWEEK('2014-01-01' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

If you need to get a `date` that is one week before a given date, then:

```
SELECT '2014-01-01' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select date_sub(date('2014-01-01'),INTERVAL 1 week)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
DATE_SUB(date('2014-01-01'), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

or

```
SELECT '2014-01-01' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `DATE_SUB` takes a date as the first arguement, but year week returns `yyyyww` i.e. not a date. So this:

```
SELECT yearweek('2014-01-01');
```

Returns `201352`, this is then implicitly casted to a date, since it is not a date the result is null. You can replicate this by doing:

```
SELECT DATE(yearweek('2014-01-01'));
```

So if you subtract a week from `NULL` the result is also `NULL`.

The fix is to subtract the week first, then get the year week:

```
SELECT yearweek(date_sub('2014-01-01', INTERVAL 1 WEEK));
```

And the result is `201351`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for week number??? If yes then plz try this if it will work for you

```
Select DatePart(Week, Date add(day,-7,convert(date time,'01-jan-2014')))
```

Pleas let me know if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(date) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) - 1;
```